# Simple movement goal problem

Tags: ros, navigation, simpleactionclient, move-base, move-base-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, when I try to run the following code to move the turtlebot 1 meter forward it becomes unresponsive (possibly when it is waiting for the server), and prints "None" if I do a keyboard interrupt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('robot_red')
import rospy
import actionlib

#move_base_msgs
from move_base_msgs.msg import *

def simple_move():

    rospy.init_node('simple_move')

    #Simple Action Client
    sac = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('move_base', MoveBaseAction )

    #create goal
    goal = MoveBaseGoal()

    #use self?
    #set goal
    goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = 1.0
    goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0
    goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = 'first_move'
    goal.target_pose.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()

    #start listner
    sac.wait_for_server()

    #send goal
    sac.send_goal(goal)

    #finish
    sac.wait_for_result()

    #print result
    print sac.get_result()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        simple_move()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        print "Keyboard Interrupt"
```

I think I may have to start a server seperately for the SimpleActionClient but am not sure what it would be. If anyone can describe what the problem might be I'll be eternally grateful. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45556/simple-movement-goal-problem/) by [highencast](https://answers.ros.org/users/3333/highencast/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [highencast](https://answers.ros.org/users/3333/highencast/) on 2012-10-11**:
I changed the parameter for the SimpleActionClient, but it's still stuck at wait_for_server(). Is there an actual action server I need to start separately?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-11**:
Yes, as I said in my answer, there is. The launch file is provided by the package [turtlebot_navigation](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation). Have a look at the tutorials.

**Comment by [korkor](https://answers.ros.org/users/22243/korkor/) on 2015-05-08**:
Thanks for posting, I had good use of your code to make my own basic move_base thing with Python

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-16**:
I have a simple question, what does goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0 mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The parameter you pass to `SimpleActionClient` is the name of the action, not the name of your node. Normally it's something like `move_base`. Make sure the navigation stack and move_base are running. Have a look at the [turtlebot_navigation tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-07-07**:
The link is blank for jade and kinetic.

Also http://wiki.ros.org/navigation#Tutorials is scewy- 'Setup the Navigation Stack for TurtleBot' is listed twice but goes to different pages links but similar looking content.